# Spring boot is not identifying rest repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring data rest(1.3.5.RELEASE) to create a simple rest service.
But the repository/JPA entities are not being recognized/registered, when my Application Config resides at a different package level.

Here is my sample project structure:

```
<source.root>
 - package1
   - Application.java
 - package2
   - RepositoryService.java
   - Model.java
```

In this case the RepositoryService is not exposing any rest methods.

Change in my project structure as below solves this problem.

```
<source.root>
 - package1
   - Application.java
   - package2
     - RepositoryService.java
     - Model.java
```

Is it mandatory for spring boot Application config to be present at the top level, so that it can scan the beans ?

Comment: No, it is not mandatory for the application configuration to be in a higher package.  If you will share the annotations atop Application.java, we'll be able to provide you with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

If `Application.java` is main Spring Boot class, it most probably uses `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

This annotation is composite annotation and contains also `@ComponentScan` annotation under the hood.

Now component scan by default scans current package and all the sub-packages. So with your first project structure, you excluded repositories from component scan.

To solve it you have these options:

1. Use project structure 1 and explicitly define packages to scan: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "package2")`. This is not type safe
2. Use project structure 1 and and explicitly define class from package you want to scan: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = RepositoryService.class)`. This is better option than option 1 as it is typesafe
3. Stick with opinionated Spring Boot defaults and use project structure 2. 
   Bear in mind, Spring Boot will be your best friend if you don't try to fight against its opinionated defaults. Only if you have really unbeatable reason.